# issue in connecting Laravel 7 with Postgres 12.4 using SSL in AWS RDS

Tags: laravel, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, laravel-7

If I try to connect the Laravel 7 (PHP 7.3) app with PostgreSQL 12.4 in AWS RDS through SSL, it's throwing this error

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (SQL: select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = public and table_name = roles)
```

It is working fine with PostgreSQL 11.8, the above error is throwing only for PostgreSQL 12,

Could anyone help on this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this issue, it is due to the mismatch of the protocol version in RDS and Application web server.